# commandline argument parameter limitation

Tags: c#, command-line, command-line-arguments

Language: C#
I have to pass a huge string array (built dynamically) as an argument to run an exe. 
I am thinking of acheiving it by the below 2 ways. But I am not feeling confident.

1. I can create it as one string delimited by spaces.  I can invoke the exe through Process.Start.
   Hence the running child process considers the space and holds as a string array.
   However I am unsure about the string array limitation. Suppose if my string array count exceeds more than 10,000
2. I can create it as one string delimited by a special symbol, which never fall in data. I can invoke the exe with the string. The running child process considers it as one single string, where i can  split it with the same delimiter to get the string array back. However, here i am unsure about the command size. Will that do, if the command line string length is large

Can anyone help me in letting me know the parameter size limitations

Comment: I'd suggest writing to a temp text file, creating the process with the text file as an argument, waiting for the process to finish then deleting the file.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It depends on the OS:

See [Command prompt (Cmd. exe) command-line string limitation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830473) on the Microsoft Support site.

> On computers running Microsoft Windows XP or later, the maximum length of the string that you can use at the command prompt is **8191 characters**. On computers running Microsoft Windows 2000 or Windows NT 4.0, the maximum length of the string that you can use at the command prompt is **2047 characters**.

(emphasis mine)

In regards to the size of a string array - if you have many millions of strings in a string array - you are mostly limited by the amount of memory available.

Answer (score 6):

If you are passing 10,000 arguments to a program, you should be putting those arguments in a file and reading the file from disk.

Comment: or distilling the concept down to something more manageable and letting the program determine how to obtain the information. (a query or arguments for a query, rather than a query result, for example)

Answer (score 6):

Although a bad idea, `Process.start` with `useshellexecute=false` would invoke `createprocess()` which allows for 32767 characters in the command line (although this is also the maximum size for the entire environment block)

Comment: Why would this be a bad idea?

Comment: more like unconventional idea

Answer (score 3):

You could store the arguments in a text file and pass that text file as the argument. Your application can then parse the text file to analyse the arguments.

Answer (score 2):

It is not really good practice to use command line arguments for huge arrays. Put your arguments in a configuration file instead, and just pass the filename as a command line argument.

The OS limit varies with the Windows version. It could be about 2k or 8k:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830473

Answer (score 2):

You may want to consider creating a parameter file and passing the file as the parameter.

I found this:

For OS: maximum command line lenght is 32767 characters (this limit is from unicode string structure), command prompt maximum lenght is 8192 characters (this limit is from cmd.exe). You may also check:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830473

Hope this help.

Answer (score 2):

- The limitation in Command prompt (Cmd. exe) is 8191. [Command prompt (Cmd. exe) command-line string limitation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/830473/command-prompt-cmd-exe-command-line-string-limitation)
- The limitation ***in c# code using Process*** is 32768 chars in win10.
- Tested using  Process.start()

Answer (score 2):

If starting the child process directly from the parent process is acceptable ([`UseShellExecute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute)`= false`), then you could redirect the `StandardInput` of the child process and pass arbitrary size of data throw it. Here is an example passing an array of 100000 strings and other stuff, serializing them in binary format.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (args.Length == 0)
    {
        var exeFilePath = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
        var psi = new ProcessStartInfo(exeFilePath, "CHILD");
        psi.UseShellExecute = false;
        psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        Console.WriteLine("Parent - Starting child process");
        var childProcess = Process.Start(psi);
        var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        object[] data = Enumerable.Range(1, 100000)
            .Select(i => (object)$"String-{i}")
            .Append(13)
            .Append(DateTime.Now)
            .Append(new DataTable("Customers"))
            .ToArray();
        Console.WriteLine("Parent - Sending data");
        bf.Serialize(childProcess.StandardInput.BaseStream, data);
        Console.WriteLine("Parent - WaitForExit");
        childProcess.WaitForExit();
        Console.WriteLine("Parent - Closing");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Child - Started");
        var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        Console.WriteLine("Child - Reading data");
        var data = (object[])bf.Deserialize(Console.OpenStandardInput());
        Console.WriteLine($"Child - Data.Length: {data.Length}");
        Console.WriteLine("Child - Closing");
    }
}
```

Output:

> Parent - Starting child process
>   Child - Started
>   Child - Reading data
>   Parent - Sending data
>   Parent - WaitForExit
>   Child - Data.Length: 100003
>   Child - Closing
>   Parent - Closing

This example executes in 6 sec in my machine.