# Start argument: the argument for the property "command line arguments" is too long (Microsoft Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, command-line-arguments, command-prompt

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Express Edition to develop a Console Application using C#.
In my Application, i need to provide XML files as input.
In order to debug within Visual Studio IDE, i will be using "Command Line arguments" space within

**Project Properties -> Debug -> Command Line arguments**

I am providing 100+ files as input in order to check the outcome. By doing this, An Error Message pops up  saying,

**Start argument: the argument for the property "command line arguments" is too long**.

I was able to run the same no. of files (100+) using Command Prompt.
Same is not possible when i try to Run/Debug using CLA option within Visual Studio.

What is the maximum size of characters i could provide within **Project Properties -> Debug -> Command Line arguments**?
Is this an issue in Visual Studio which limits the input character?

Comment: Could you make a batch file that has the parameters in it, and have VS launch the batch file?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the response. Yes I could do that. I could also provide a folder path option from which i could fetch all the files internally within code. These will help me to run the code successfully. However, the application requirements are in such a way that I need to provide only XML file paths as the input in Command Line Arguments. This could be done in different approaches. But, i wanted to know particularly about the scenario I specified. Like is there any way I could provide maximum file paths as input in CLA without facing this error.

Comment: According to your question, the command line arguments can only input limited characters. Regarding the limit on how many characters there are,  you can refer to the link of this question: [commandline argument parameter limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9115279/commandline-argument-parameter-limitation).